# different ways to display errors in a Rails view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, model

In my views I've been always including the following section (not very DRY):

```
<% if @model.errors.any? %>
  ...
  <% @model.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
    ...
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

However, Rails also provides the `flash[:error]` functionality. Is it meant just for single failure messages like a controller exception? Or should I use `flash[:error]` for everything and copy over model errors into that hash?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Things like model errors can live in a partial; pass in the object in question as a local:

```
<%= form_for(@micropost) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', :object => f.object %>
```

Personally, I feel the flash scope is for a different class of messages, but there's nothing fundamentally "incorrect" about using it for validation errors as well.

Comment: Ha, thanks for reminding me about partials! Don't know why I didn't think of it in the beginning.

Comment: You can also abstract it further along the lines of what people are already used to with `if f.object.errors.any?`, which tends to help if you're doing nested associations and stuff.